# Why my crontab request dont work to call a python script

Tags: python, cron, raspberry-pi3

On Raspberry Pi 3B+ running on Raspberry Pi OS 64.
Trying to make a Python script executed every minute but don't work.
To edit crontab, I use :

```
sudo crontab -e
```

And put this line in file :

```
*/1 * * * * sudo /bin/python3 /home/pi/Documents/script_test01.py`
```

I also tried : `*/1 * * * * sudo python3 /home/pi/Documents/script_test01.py`

Here my script, simply publish in a MQTT broker (script works by direct call in shell: `python3 script_test01.py`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

client_mqtt = mqtt.Client("Script-crontab")

client_mqtt.connect("localhost")
client_mqtt.publish("RandomTempValuesSimulator", "Hello !")
client_mqtt.disconnect()

exit()
```

I did a stop and start cron service with :

```
sudo systemctl stop cron.service
sudo systemctl start cron.service
```

Nothing more happened.

Comment: Is your account allowed to run `sudo` without a password prompt?

Comment: Why don't you just run this from root's crontab so you don't need `sudo`?

Comment: I've already tried without sudo... same result... nothing.

Comment: If the script isn't running, this isn't a Python problem, it's a Linux problem and you should ask in [linux.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
When i did `crontab -l`, i've got `no crontab for pi user`.

Problem solved without "sudo" with command `crontab -e` and edit the blank crontab file openned and put this command : `*/1 * * * * /bin/python3 /home/pi/Documents/script_test01.py`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your script is executable. The interpreter is usually at `/usr/bin/python3` (not `/bin/python3`) but you don't need that since you have the `#!` on top of your script.

Why are you editing `root`'s crontab? Why not just your own? Check your `/var/log/syslog` files for any errors in the execution.

Comment: The script doesn't need to be executable if you invoke it using `python scriptname`

Comment: >Apr 27 18:39:01 espikabox CRON[154436]: (root) CMD (/bin/python3 /home/pi/Documents/script_test01.py)
>Apr 27 18:39:01 espikabox CRON[154434]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

Comment: Okay. Looks like it's trying to email you the output but you're not getting it since you don't have email set up locally. One option is to add a `2>&1 > /tmp/output.log` to the end of your command so that the output goes into a file and you can read it.